# Unclear SCSS error Unexpected character '' (1:4)

Tags: sass

I am getting this unclear error from SCSS: `Unexpected character '' (1:4)`

> `Failed to compile
>   ./components/layout/Layout.scss
>   ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:4)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   (Source code omitted for this binary file)`

while this is my SCSS File `Layout.scss`:

```
@import './sass-tools';
@import './normalize';
@import './custom-base';

.page-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max-width: $page-max-width;
    margin: 0 auto;

    &.nobp {
        max-width: none;
        width: 1224px;
    }
}

.page-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: $white;

    .nobp & {
        width: 1024px;
    }
}
```

This is my folder structure:

```
./components/layout/
 ∟ Layout.jsx
 ∟ Layout.scss
 ∟ Layout.test.js
 ∟ _fonts.scss
 ∟ _sass-tools.scss
 ∟ custom-base.scss
 ∟ normalize.scss
```

For me it is unclear what character  `'' (1:4)` is ought to be. I believe my Webpack config is ok, I can post it if you want, but `SCSS` has worked so far (with other files) in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The SASS compiler output is bullshit: This is what happened:

`Layout.scss` imports
`custom-base.scss` imports
`fonts.scss`

that includes `.woff` and `.woff2` files. I think I still need to add a loader for those

Comment: That's nice. Post question and answered yourself.

Comment: Ia that ironic? Are you the minus 1 guy? You realize how time works? You also realize this might be helpful to others? You also realize there is an option on SO to post a question with an answer to help others? Maybe you don't.